# Export file stored in SQL table by saving file hash into local file

Tags: sql-server, file, hash, ssms

Let me start by saying that I know very little about SQL - I can get into the SQL Server Management Studio and see my database, tables, columns, etc. I can run queries to verify the data exists.

We recently retired from a SaaS product and received a db of our data, then installed it on a local SQL Server. I can get to the data needed with the exceptions of files that were attached to the records.

There is a table with the file stored as a hash (don't laugh if I get the terminology twisted a bit), and the vendor suggested that we could "extract the attachments from the SQL in SSMS. You should be able to save the file hash from SQL into a new file with the extension to get it to open.".

I don't need to extract all the files, I just need to be able to extract them for specific records if the need arises, one at a time. I saw something dealing with MySQL called Dump File, and that seemed to be the sort of path I need - the ability to run a query that calls a particular record and saves it into a local file. I would then change the file extension manually.

Is there a semi-easy way to do this? Do I need to provide any other information? Thanks for your help.

Comment: We'd need to see the table definition at the very least.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the full file is in a SQL Server `varbinary(max)` or `image` column, you can extract it to a local file by running a PowerShell script.  There are many examples on the internet, like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx), the gist of which is:

```
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;            
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +             
                        "Integrated Security=True;" +            
                        "Initial Catalog=$Database";            
$con.Open();            
            
# New Command and Reader            
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con;            
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();            
            
# Create a byte array for the stream.            
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)            
            
# Looping through records            
While ($rd.Read())            
{            
    Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0));                    
    # New BinaryWriter            
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write;            
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;            
               
    $start = 0;            
    # Read first byte stream            
    $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);            
    While ($received -gt 0)            
    {            
       $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);            
       $bw.Flush();            
       $start += $received;            
       # Read next byte stream            
       $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);            
    }            
            
    $bw.Close();            
    $fs.Close();            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. The table structure does indeed use varbinary (max).
 - RecID (varchar(42)
 - CreatedDateTime (datetime)
 - AttachType (varchar(10))
 - AttachFlags (varchar(200))
 - FilePath (varchar(500))
 - FileContents (varbinary(max))
 - FileExt (varchar(10))
 - LastModTimeStamp (timestamp)

I appreciate the code and will give that a shot.